# Trying to join the next line to a line ending with backslash in sed

Tags: shell, scripting, sed

There are two files file.txt and file1.txt

```
$ cat file.txt
Linux
Administration
Scripting
Tips and Tricks
Windows
Administration
Database
Administration of Oracle
Administration of Mysql
Security
Network
Online\
Security
Productivity\
Google Search\
Tips
"Web Based Time Tracking,
Web Based Todo list and
Reduce Key Stores etc"
$

$ cat file1.txt

AIX
Solaris\
Unix\ 
Linux 
HPUX
```

I am trying to append next line to a line ending with backslash with the above files as input.

The o/p from file.txt is shown below and it is correct

```
$ sed ':loop /\\$/N; s/\\\n */ /; tloop' file.txt
Linux
Administration
Scripting
Tips and Tricks
Windows
Administration
Database
Administration of Oracle
Administration of Mysql
Security
Network
Online Security
Productivity Google Search Tips
"Web Based Time Tracking,
Web Based Todo list and
Reduce Key Stores etc"
$
```

If i again run above lines with file1.txt as input then  o/p is not correct

```
$ sed ':loop /\\$/N; s/\\\n */ /; tloop' file1.txt
AIX
Solaris Unix\ 
Linux 
HPUX
```

Can anyone pls explain why file1.txt is not showing correct o/p.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;$!N;s/\\\s*\n\s*/ /;ta;P;D' file
```

This takes care spaces either side of the newline.

Answer (score 0):

You have spaces after the backslash. Try:

```
sed ':loop /\\ *$/N; s/\\ *\n */ /; tloop' file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But We have spaces in both the files after backslash . If i would run sed ':loop /\\$/N; s/\\\n */ /; tloop' file.txt then the o/p is correct but not with file1.txt

Comment: Yes i tried your code in both the files and correct o/p is coming with both the files but my concern is if  i run my previous code  sed ':loop /\\$/N; s/\\\n */ /; tloop' abc.txt with file and file1 one shows the correct o/p and other doesn't and we have spaces after the backslashes in both these files

Comment: Not in the file contents you posted here, there's only an additional space after "Unix\". If you have different files than you post here, there's no way we can find out what's wrong.

Comment: additional space is also after Google Search\ in file.txt but it's giving correct o/p then howcome the same code is not working with Unix\

Comment: There is **no** additional space after "Google Search\" in the file content you posted in your question. Try adding one by hand after "Google Search\" and see if your script still works.